# Validates_attachment_presence does not work on nested object, so parent get save, why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nested, paperclip

Rails 3.0
Paperclip 2.3.5

I have two models Order and Replay, Replay is nested in Order.  Replay sole purpose is to save a file with paperclip to an independent table in the DB.

My problem is that validates_attachment_presence is not doing is job, it doesn't trigger an error if my upload file is empty.  So the order get save in the orders table without a the replay being saved in the replays table.

And what is stranger is that validates_attachment_size work like a charm.

To put thing into perspective I had the same problem before using paperclip, validates_presence_of was not doing it's job.

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_one :replay
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :replay

end

class Replay < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to :order
  has_attached_file :replay

  validates_attachment_presence :replay                                               
  validates_attachment_size :replay, :greater_than => 1.megabyte

end
```

Here's my form view:

```
<%= form_for @order, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_messages %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field:name %>
  </p>
  <%= f.fields_for :replay do |builder| %>
  <p>
    <%= builder.label :replay, "Replay file:" %><br />
    <%= builder.file_field :replay %>
  </p>
  <% end %>
  <p><%= f.submit %></p>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add in Order :

```
validates_associated :replay
```

Comment: and validates_presence_of :replay ?

Comment: It worked... I'm somewhat still looking for an explanation for this strange behavior.  Tks.